# Dealing with an array of checkboxes in php

Tags: php, php-5.3, checkbox

Ok so I am making an emailing form and need to get a bunch of items in a checkbox array to be printed... or converted into a string... so they can be made into a variable...

here is what the form looks like:

[image]

And there is the html behind it:

```
 <th valign="top" scope="row">Receive further information_on: </th>
              <td width="27%"><input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Rapid Auto Roll Doors" id="Information on" />
Rapid Auto Roll Doors<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Swingflex Doors" id="Information on" />
Swingflex Doors<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Floor Guides" id="Information on" />
Floor Guides<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Visiflex Strip Doors" id="Information on" />
Visiflex Strip Doors<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="PVC-Strip / Sheets" id="Information on" />
PVC-Strips / Sheets</td>
              <td width="37%"><input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Efaflex Doors" id="Information on" />
Efaflex Doors <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Traffic Doors" id="Information on" />
Traffic Doors<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Fold Up Doors" id="Information on" />
Fold Up Doors <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Dock Levellers" id="Information on" />
Dock Levellers<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Information_on[]" value="Other" id="Information on" />
Other
</p></td>
```

they all have the same name: Information_on[]

ok so the next part is to convert the "selected" ones into a php string that would look like the following format:

$outputExample = "selecteditem1, selecteditem2, selecteditem3.";

but of course with the values set in the checkboxes.

So I have no idea how to do this, to have them be gathered and checked to see which titles need to be sent in PHP... thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? This is pretty darn easy to do. Start by doing `print_r($_POST)` and go from there.

Comment: $outputExample = implode(', ', $_POST['Information_on']);

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form is POST, since you're making a contact form. Then you could do something like this:

```
$info = $_POST['Information_on'];
$outputExample = implode(', ', $info);
```

Remember that where a checkbox is blank, you won't get any value in your $_POST array (not even an "off" - just the way it works!).

Answer (score 0):

Remember to always sanitize your data inputs!

```
$info = filter_var_array($_POST['Information_on'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$CSV = implode(', ', $info)
```